# Entry Framework 4..5: Query Builder

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I'm a newby to Entry Framework. I'm working though Julia Lerman's book and I'm stuck with Query Builder method. I get the following compile error:

```
    Error   1   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Chapter2ConsoleApp.Contact>' does not 
 contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 
'System.Linq.Queryable.Where<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, 
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,bool>>)' has some invalid arguments  
C:\EF\ProgrammingEntityFramework\Chapter2ConsoleApp\Program.cs  59  32  
Chapter2ConsoleApp
```

There's the code.

```
using (SampleEntities context = new SampleEntities())
            {
              var contacts = context.Contacts.Where("it.FirstName = 'Robert'").OrderBy("it.LastName");
                                foreach (Contact contact in contacts)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",
                                contact.FirstName.Trim(),
                                contact.LastName);
                }
            }
            Console.Write("Press Enter...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

A Linq to entity with a lambda works OK. When I look at the bad code via IntelliSense I can see that there is a Where method. Finally, I've tried a cast `[(IObjectContextAdapter)]` on the context but then I couldn't get the Contact method.

Would anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code below (make sure you import `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure` namespace)

```
var contacts = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<Contact>()
                .Where("it.FirstName = 'Robert'")
                .OrderBy("it.LastName");
```

Thanks,
Kinvi